# Freezing Row and Column both same time in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been trying to freeze **Row (A2)** and **Column (B1)** same
time by **View > Freeze panes**

[image]

but unable to do. Please let me know, how to do?

With Regards

EinfoMail

Answer (score 0):

First be sure the highlighted cell (current cell) is inside the row and inside the column you wish to freeze.

Having done the above, Freeze Panes again. This works Excel 2007 (thereabouts) up to the current version.

You may need to do a full Repair of Office as well.

Also try a completely new workbook to see if Freeze Panes works in the new workbook.